# Code Generater interprets NUMERIC(20,0) as BIGDECIMAL while it should be interpreted as Long

Tags: sql, types, numeric, jooq

I have a table with a field name "BID" with its data type set as NUMERIC(20,0). Now i know that it will never be a decimal/float value but always be a int/long i.e a natural number.

Is there a way for the code generator to make the variable inside the generated model class a Long as opposed to java.math.BigDecimal which it makes currently. Can it be set in jooq.properties??

Comment: Why not use int or longer in the DBMS?

Comment: @gbn: NUMERIC(20,0) can hold somewhat larger numbers than for instance `BIGINT` (`Long` in Java, which only has 19 decimals)...

Comment: @Lukas Eder: NUMERIC(20,0) (+- 9.99 E20) is only just above 64 signed int (+- 9.2E18). Higher numerics, yes, but upto 19/20 is a classic (eg legacy for pre-SQL Server 2000) workaround for the 32 bit limit

Comment: @gbn: I see. I realised when I calculated the decimal digits in a long, that it's actually 19. I first thought it was less...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "feature" is currently only available for the Oracle database, where `NUMBER` is the only numeric type available. Using Oracle with jOOQ, `NUMBER(20, 0)` would map to `java.math.BigInteger` instead of `java.math.BigDecimal`.

This behaviour will also be available for other RDBMS in the next release 1.6.3. See

https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jooq/ticket/639

Besides that, overriding of data type mappings in the code generator is currently not possible, but you could use `BIGINT` as suggested by gbn, if you don't really need 20 decimal digits. `BIGINT` can hold most 19-digit decimals...